Why is it written in an 'it is that' structure?
“It is that you come home from India on  what is called the leave—what we can call  en permission?”
(Murder on the Orient Express by Agatha Christie)
Why is it written in an 'it is that' structure? It's not even a cleft sentence.
below is the context


“Ah! my dear old friend,” he said, “you see I have become what they call the snob! The first class, I feel it should be attended to before the second class. Next, I think, we will interview the
good-looking Colonel Arbuthnot.”
Finding the Colonel’s French to be of a severely limited description, Poirot conducted his interrogatory in English.
Arbuthnot’s name, age, home address and exact military standing were all ascertained. Poirot proceeded:
“It is that you come home from India on  what is called the leave—what we can call  en permission?”
Colonel Arbuthnot, uninterested in what a pack  of foreigners called  anything, replied with true British brevity, “Yes.”
“But you do not come home on the P. & O. boat?”
“No.”
“Why not?”


Statements in English can be spoken as questions. if there is rising intonition. However, what stands out here is come instead of came. Also, the determiner the with  leave as someone below pointed out.

[Why is X written as Y]

Poirot is a French-speaking Belgian, and the author (Agatha Christie) writes his dialogue in such a way as to appear "foreign", as he is speaking with an accent.
The "It is that" would appear to be influenced by the translation of "Est ce que", the French way of forming questions, and used by Christie to mark his dialogue as having an accent.  I can't say why Poirot phrases this as a statement.  And we may never know, it may just be an idiosyncracy.

Oh right, thank you so much for your answer.

Note that "on the leave"  is also a non-idiomatic use of "the", again to show that Poirot has a French accent.  More of a mystery is what Arbuthnot means by a "rail convoy car", as this expression seems not to appear in any other book or context.

@JamesK - I have stared at the OP's question for some while, and I cannot see any mention (by anyone) of a "rail convoy car". Is it present in a copy of the book that you have to hand?

@JamesK - in any case I suspect it's a military term. Arbuthnot was talking about his visit to Mesopotamia/Iraq (at the time mandated to Britain to control by the League of Nations following the break-up of the Ottoman Empire). Christie was usually pretty good on detail (she gets the AOC Commanding bit right; 'Mespot' was, unusually, militarily run by the RAF).

@JamesK - TE Lawrence destroyed a 'Turkish rail convoy" in Mespot in September 1917.

Of course the 'Commanding' in 'A. O. C. Commanding' is redundant. My mistake; also the original Christie text used the spaces and periods customary at the time.

@MichaelHarvey yes... I was curious why he didn't come home on the P & O boat,  so read more of the book, and it describes his journey by "rail convey car".  My guess is that it is a passenger car attached to a freight train. Perhaps a carriage for enlisted soldiers charged with protecting a train.

@JamesK - in my version it is 'convoy' with an 'o', and I should think that a military rail convoy might differ from an ordinary train e.g. by having another train full of armed soldiers run slightly in advance, by being itself full of heavily armed soldiers, etc.

You write "is it that" in your answer, matching the word-for-word translation from French "est-ce que", however in the question title and body it says "it is that". I am not sure which one is in the original, but it might be good to match the question in your answer.

I hadn't noticed.  Yes the book has "It is that..."

... which might be close to "C'est que ..." in French as the start of a statement rather than of a question.

"It is that" is a clever way to show C'est que OR Est-ce que etc.  even though it really isn't. Since English intonation can carry a question. It's the come instead of came and "the" leave.

Whatever the justification for this particular construction, the point is that Poirot is not a fluent speaker of English, is it not? He is a fictional character and this is the way the author has written him.
